# Reflection - inherited fields all null or empty

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class (with superclass) for which I want to check that all fields are either NULL, or if it's a Collection, that it's empty. With the following code I am able to check for NULL and whether it's a Collection, but I can't seem to cast the Collection to check it's size:

```
public static boolean objectIsEmpty(Object object) {
    for (Class<?> c = object.getClass(); c != null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
        Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                if (field.get(object) != null) {
                    if (field.getType().equals(List.class)) {
                        // System.err.println("len " +
                        // Array.getLength(field.get(object)));
                    }
                    if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                        System.err.println(Collection.class.cast(field).size());
                        // ClassCastException thrown here
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // Should not occur with setAccessible(true), return false just
                // in case
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
```

But that results in java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.reflect.Field to java.util.Collection

How do I get the size of the Lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cast field to collection. You can cast the field object to collection. Try this:

```
System.err.println(Collection.class.cast(field.get(object)).size());
```

Comment: Oh god, of course. Makes total sense now I think of it, thanks a lot for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

below code will convert blank empty strings to null using java reflection:

```
package reflection;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * @author Sachin Rane on 7/1/21
 */
public class ReflectionUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setName("Sachin");
        employee.setCity("");//this will set to null

        replaceAllEmptyStringFieldsWithNull(employee);
        
        if (null == employee.getCity()) {
            System.out.println("replaceAllEmptyStringFieldsWithNull converted blank string to null");
        }
    }

    public static void replaceAllEmptyStringFieldsWithNull(Object object) {
        if (null == object) {
            return;
        }
        Method[] methodsOfObject = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        Method methodRef = null;
        try {
            for (Method method : methodsOfObject) {
                methodRef = method;
                method.setAccessible(true);
                if (isGetType(method)) {
                    //skip list, set, map or array objects
                    if (skipObjectsCheck(method)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (method.getReturnType() == String.class) {
                        String value = (String) method.invoke(object);
                        if ("".equals(value)) {
                            Field field = getFieldByFieldName(object, method.getName().replace("get", ""));
                            if (null != field) {
                                field.setAccessible(true);
                                field.set(object, null);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        replaceAllEmptyStringFieldsWithNull(method.invoke(object));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            System.out.println("IllegalAccessException while invoking method for class : " + object.getClass().getName()
                    + " and method : " + (null != methodRef ? methodRef.getName() : null));
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            System.out.println("InvocationTargetException while invoking method for class : " + object.getClass().getName()
                    + " and method : " + (null != methodRef ? methodRef.getName() : null));
        }

    }

    static boolean skipObjectsCheck(Method method) {
        if (method.getReturnType().isArray()) return true;
        if (!(method.getGenericReturnType() instanceof ParameterizedType)) return false;
        ParameterizedType parametrizedReturnType = (ParameterizedType) method.getGenericReturnType();
        if (parametrizedReturnType.getRawType() == List.class
                || parametrizedReturnType.getRawType() == Set.class
                || parametrizedReturnType.getRawType() == Map.class) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static Field getFieldByFieldName(Object obj, String fieldName) {
        Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field f : fields){
            if (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
                return f;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    static boolean isGetType(Method method) {
        if (method.getName().startsWith("get")) return true;
        return false;
    }

    private static class Employee {
        String name;
        String city;
        List<String> list;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public List<String> getList() {
            return list;
        }

        public void setList(List<String> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
replaceAllEmptyStringFieldsWithNull converted blank string to null
```